# using workbook name in sumifs formula

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to use `sumifs` to generate a sum of a specific column in a sheet called '`Details Sheet`' in a different workbook based on checking that 2 other columns in '`details sheet`' match values in the current worksheet.
Right now I have the following

```
 ThisWB = ActiveWorkbook.Name
```

At the start of the macro.

Later in the macro, I switch focus to the sheet/workbook that I am working out of, and I use:

```
Dim sheet As String
sheet = "'[" & ThisWB & "]Details Sheet'!"
Range("F3").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=SUMIFS(INDIRECT(sheet & ""$H:$H"")),INDIRECT(sheet & ""$D:$D"")),""=""&$B3,INDIRECT(sheet & ""$E:$E"")),""=""&$C3)"
```

This produces an error. I have tried various other ways to reference that sheet and none of them work.

When I reference the sheet with the full name of the workbook, i.e. `[workbook1]Details Sheet!'$D:$D`, that does work.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Why do you need INDIRECT in there?

Comment: i have tried without the indirect also, but that did not work. the indirect allows me to create a reference using text and this seemed like a logical use of that

Answer (score 0):

You need the `Formula` property rather than `FormulaR1c1` and you don't need INDIRECT because you are doing the concatenation in the code, not the formula itself:

```
Range("F3").Formula = _
    "=SUMIFS(" & sheet & "$H:$H," & sheet & "$D:$D,""=""&$B3," & sheet & "$E:$E,""=""&$C3)"
```